# child of angularjs component

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope, components, parent-child

How can a child DOM of an angularjs component access the component's variable values?

To illustrate, I am using angular official website first component example.  I added a div inside the component.

```
<span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}</span>

<!--The following is the child of the component, 
    which is not showing component's variable as expected  -->
<div ng-controller="InnerCtrl">
  Inside the component, Name: {{$ctrl.hero.name}}
</div>
```

Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oYjwkZbzh89z2hedb9g6?p=preview)

Comment: Comment out line `console.log('InnerCtrl, ctrl.hero =', ctrl.hero);` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you, dfsq!  It works after I comment out! But I need to use the ctrl.hero object in my controller, too.  How do I reference to hero object in my inner controller innerCtrl?